# How can I open an aspx page via using document manager button in Telerik Rad Editor Tool?

Tags: c#, telerik

I have a Telerik RadEditor. At the editor there are tools such as "hyperlink manager" and "Indent" etc.
At the hyperlink manager there is the "document manager".

And I show all images in the FileManager using an .aspx page.

Clicking document manager buton can I open the filemanager.aspx?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify the LinkManager dialog as explained here: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/editor/examples/externaldialogspath/defaultcs.aspx so that it will do your bidding.